# Where Does Visual Studio Remember Which Folders are "Namespace Providers"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, namespaces

OK, this may be really simple, but it is Friday and it has been a long week. I can't seem to find an answer for the life of me.

Basically, I have a project in which the Namespace Provider property has been set. When a colleague gets the up to date code from the repository, these properties do not seem to appear at all? (i.e. there is no "Namespace Provider" entry in the properties window)..

What could be causing this? I am thinking he may need an update for VS2008 or something? I have **never** had issues with this/like this before!

Ideas? :)

Thanks a lot!

### Update

We have now verified that the machine has VS2008 SP1 - Still no dice :(

.. and we have completely deleted all the files in the folder and done another "GET" from the repo (crappy VSS) - I have a distinct feeling that there are some residual "web site" project files that were not deleted from the repo, and are causing VS to misinterpret the project type somehow..

Will let you know once I can prove :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always thought that Namespace Provider was a ReSharper property.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for slapping this stupid geek in the face with one line of knowledge that has made him feel like an absolute moron.

You are indeed correct - "Namespace Provider" is listed under "Resharper"..

I have also just remembered I am the only with a R# license on the team..

I don't know if I want to laugh or cry.

Thanks again :)

Comment: I have gotten so used to Namespace Provider I had it in my head it was part of VS.. I R STUPID GEEK.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of visual studio are you using, and which is he?

A lot of these types of issues arise when one dev is using Team Suite and the other using standard edition.

Ninja

Comment: Both of us are using VS2008 Pro with SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems like the "namespace provider" option is stored in the .suo file for the solution.  Try opening the SUO on something like notepad++ that has file monitoring and see for yourself.

Change it, save the file, the file watcher notifies of an update.  This is possibly because the namespace provider setting doesn't do anything to the compiled code, it's just information VS uses when creating new class files (theory).

Comment: I thought you might have been on to something then, however (and sadly) I don't think this is the case.. May be on to something - will update Q.